# Did Penzias and Wilson really make a *picture* of the CMB?

Tags: cosmology, history, cosmic-microwave-background

Did Penzias and Wilson really made a *picture* (graphical picture of a sky map using a computer) of the CMB, as stated on the web, or is it completely wrong ?

Indeed, If I consider what they say here :

https://www.eclatsdelumiere.fr/tag/cmb
[image]

"Le CMB observé par Penzias et Wilson en 1964. Crédit : NASA."
(translation : CMB observed by Penzias and Wilson in 1964. source : NASA)

I have strong doubt that this plot was really obtained by them in 1965 (computing at that time would not allow to have such a beautiful picture).

Did they have a plot, or is this plot from *modern* observations ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Penzias and Wilson did not make an all sky map of the CMB.

It's difficult to say what the map is. It could be a map made by WMAP or Planck? I'd bet [WMAP](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilkinson_Microwave_Anisotropy_Probe), since Planck was an ESA mission.

Comment: Thank you. Ok, apparently, this is COBE plots. So they claim that Penzias and Wilson made this plot wrongly.

Comment: No, I believe it is WMAP. https://www.forbes.com/sites/startswithabang/2018/09/18/this-is-how-we-know-the-cosmic-microwave-background-comes-from-the-big-bang/#44dfa40371c3

Comment: You are right. sorry. Indeed, the green plot is from WMAP. While the orange plot similar here is from COBE : https://lambda.gsfc.nasa.gov/product/cobe/dmr_image.cfm (apart that this is orange instead of green)